# How to query $in with objectid in meteors existing collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using existing Mongodb in meteor. I don't know how to query `$in` with `ObjectId()`

```
Users = new Mongo.Collection('users', {idGeneration: 'MONGO'});

var ids = ['55549158f046be124e3fdee7',
'5539d937f046be0e2502aefc',
'55548e10f046bee14c3fdeed',
'55549938f046be99493fdef8' ];

Users.find({_id:{$in: ids}}).fetch(); //returns empty array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first cast the array ids to an array of ObjectIds using the **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method:

```
var Users = new Mongo.Collection('users', {idGeneration: 'MONGO'}),
    ids = [
        '55549158f046be124e3fdee7',
        '5539d937f046be0e2502aefc',
        '55548e10f046bee14c3fdeed',
        '55549938f046be99493fdef8' 
    ],
    mids = ids.map(function(id) { return new Mongo.ObjectID(id); });

Users.find({"_id":{"$in": mids}}).fetch();
```

Comment: @BlueBells No worries